# oop structure for make class such as PDO class structure

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, pdo, orm

How to make class structure like PDO or ORM

```
 $query = DB::table('users')->select('name');

 $users = $query->addSelect('age')->get();
```

OR

```
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->bindvalue(':u',intval($_SESSION['userId']),PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $stmt->execute();
```

What is returned in to $query or $stmt?

how to design class structure like them?

Thank you

**EDIT**

```
 $query = DB::table('users')->select('name');
 meaning : 
 function select(){
  //
  return $this;
 }
```

what's returned in to $query for this structure :

```
 $query->addSelect('age')->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDO is done by returning a new class (`PDOStatement`) with its own methods ([read more about it](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)), but it would be the same as:

```
<?php
class ClassOne
{
    private $connection;
    public function __construct($database_stuff)
    {
        $this->connection = $database_stuff;
    }

    public function prepare($sql)
    {
        // Code that does something with the $sql
        // Then return a new class
        return new ClassTwo($this);
    }
}

class ClassTwo
{
    private $ClassOne;

    public function __construct(ClassOne $Class)
    {
        $this->ClassOne = $Class;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        // Code that does something with ClassOne
    }
}

# Start that initial class
$Class = new ClassOne('database:type;host=example;etc=yadayada');
# Do class one method
$query = $Class->prepare("SELECT * FROM fake_table");
# $query is now ClassTwo, so you do method from ClassTwo
$query->execute();
```

The ability to chain methods together is achieved because the current method returns the object back in the form of `$this`:

```
<?php
    class   DBClass
    {
        protected   $connection,
                    $value;

        public  function __construct($connection)
        {
            $this->connection   =   $connection;
        }

        public  function prepare($value)
        {
            $this->value    =   $value;
            # Return the object
            return $this;
        }

        public  function execute()
        {
            echo $this->value;
            # Return the object
            return $this;
        }
    }

    $con    =   new DBClass("login creds");
    $con->prepare("update stuff if stuff = 'things'")->execute();
?>
```

Comment: Thank, can use __call for add Closure method in this class??!